# Ilog output to XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, ilog

I have an output and I convert it to XML but the XML appears with some tags out of place or miss-written.

Here's the Ilog output:

```
Y = [[[7.5
             7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5]
             [9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6]
             [8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889
             8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889]
             [8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759
             8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759]]
         [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]];
X = [[[7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5]
             [9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6 9.6]
             [8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889
             8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889 8.8889]
             [8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759
             8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759 8.2759]]
         [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]];
```

The XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Solutions>
<output_quantity>
<Y/>  <--- one of the problem's
<Y>7.5<Y/>
<Y>7.5</Y><---  the other problem
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
<Y>7.5</Y>
</output_quantity>
<output_quantity>
<Y/>
<Y>9.6</Y>
<Y>9.6</Y>
<Y>9.6</Y>
<Y>9.6</Y>
<Y>9.6</Y>
```

Here is my code:

```
public void process(String s) throws SAXException {
        String[] elements = s.split("");
        int flag = 0, flag2 = 0;
        atts.clear();

        if (s.contains("Y = ") || Y == 1) {

            if (Y == 0) {
                Y++;
                th.startElement("", "", "Solutions", atts);
                th.startElement("", "", "output_quantity", atts);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].equals(" ") && flag == 1 && flag2 == 1
                        || elements[i].equals("]")) {

                    flag = 0;
                    if (flag2 == 1) {
                        th.endElement("", "", "Y");

                        if (elements[i].equals("]")) {
                            th.endElement("", "", "output_quantity");
                            th.startElement("", "", "output_quantity", atts);
                        }
                    }
                    flag2 = 0;
                }
                if (!elements[i].equals("[") && !elements[i].equals("Y")
                        && !elements[i].equals("=") && !elements[i].equals(" ")
                        && !elements[i].equals("]") && !elements[i].equals(";")) {
                    if (flag == 0)

                        th.startElement("", "", "Y", atts);
                    // Y++;
                    flag = 1;
                    flag2 = 1;
                    th.characters(elements[i].toCharArray(), 0,
                            elements[i].length());

                    // System.out.println("Information " + elements[i]);

                }
            }
            if (s.contains("]]];")) {
                // Y++;
                th.endElement("", "", "output_quantity");
                // th.endElement("", "", "Solutions");
            }

        }
```

Is there a way of removing those tags and correct the misplaced "/"?
Regards